# upload file using jersey 2 client : convert from inputstream of FormDataParam to File

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

[image]

**Applications Flow**: 
The Above picture gives an idea of the applications consuming other applications REST API's. Assume each box as each individual REST applications exposes REST API's and consumes other applications API's. '**C**' is the actual end point that exposes an API for uploading a file (.pdf) and that was consumed by application B with added validations and security layer. My part of development is for "**A**" application and I do not have any control on **B** and **C** except consuming API's exposed by **B**.

**my Development task**: As said, My part of the task is to develop **A**( REST applicaton) that exposes an API to upload file with some added business logic and will consume an API of **B**'s application that will intern uses the **C** application to upload the document.

**Build.sbt**:

```
val jerseyVersion = "2.23.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.glassfish.jersey.containers" % "jersey-container-servlet" % jerseyVersion,
  "org.glassfish.jersey.media" % "jersey-media-multipart" % jerseyVersion,
  "org.glassfish.jersey.media" % "jersey-media-json-jackson" % jerseyVersion,
  "org.glassfish.jersey.ext" % "jersey-bean-validation" % jerseyVersion,
  "org.glassfish.jersey.core" % "jersey-server" % jerseyVersion,
  "org.glassfish.jersey.core" % "jersey-client" % jerseyVersion,
  "org.glassfish.jersey.containers" % "jersey-container-grizzly2-http" % jerseyVersion,
  "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "3.1.0",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.9.8"
)
```

**Code**:

```
@Path("/resource/document")
@Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces("application/json")
public Response<String> uploadDocument(@FormDataParam("empData") FormDataBodyPart empJson,
                                            @FormDataParam("source") String source,
                                            @FormDataParam("description") String description,
                                            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadFileInputStream,
                                            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData){

    FormDataMultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();

    final EmployeeDetails empDetails = empJson.getValueAs(EmployeeDetails.class);

    multiPart = multiPart.field("empData",empDetails.getName());
    multiPart = multiPart.field("country",empDetails.getCountry());

    multiPart = multiPart.field("source",source)
            .field("sourceDescription", description)
            .field("docDate", LocalDate.now().toString())
            .field("docLanguage","English")
            .field("recDate",LocalDate.now().toString())
            .field("additionalInformation",fileMetaData.getFileName())
            .field("docName",fileMetaData.getName());

    /*FormDataBodyPart bodyPart = new FormDataBodyPart("file",uploadFileInputStream.,MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);*/
    return null;
}
```

**Issue**:
This is the 1st time I am using Jersey lib. As you can see from the above code I have used `@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadFileInputStream` to receive the file input stream and I need to send this to the Application **B**'s api that does the rest of the work of uploading the file to final end point. But, the challenge is how to I send it to the Application **B**'s upload api. I don't want to store the InputStream received into file in the server location where application **A** is running and create a File object and send it. Is there any way to convert this InputStream into File object or any other object so that I can send it to the **B** Application's upload API using jersey 2 client. 
Let me know if any further information or code is needed to help me resolve the issue.
**Just a note. The below code is not complete as I am stuck at converting the InputStream to File to send it to the B's upload API.**

**Tech Stack** :

> Java 8 ,
>   IntelliJ ,
>   SBT build ,
>   jersey 2

**limitations**: 
I am using jersey 2 for server and client and I can not change the technology stack like instead of jersey I can not use Spring Boot or any other and I have to stick to jersey but I am open to use any version of Jersey( jersey 1 or jersey 2)

Comment: did you get solution ?

Comment: nope. I haven't ;-(

Comment: you don't have need to convert to file . just manipulate it with bytestream array and use anywhere

Comment: if you read my question carefully , the challenge is not about using the bytestream. I have to send it to another REST api which accept File object. so the question is how do i convert this byteSteam to File object with out being stored in locally as a temp file.

Comment: that you have to store like temp , but that will down performance . but i can suggest one good solution , convert file to 64base on front-end like in js , and then pass it as it is to another server anywhere like string , and decode it on end . but its possible if you have another server control bc you have to change your endpoint implementation